# How to configure Spring Actuator for httptrace and Rest Template?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring boot application that it executes several parallel requests, of course, using RestTemplate class.
I configured Spring actuator,to see the Http Trace.
*management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=httptrace*

When I execute: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/httptrace`
I see information but related to the request I am doing to my Spring Mvc exposed controllers, but I don't see any info related to the request I am doing internally.

So how can I achieve that? Could you show me some example?
Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Boot **`/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests`** to get all endPoints which are executed with their ***`count, exception, outcome, status, total time, etc`*** as follow.

If you want to see details for particular endPoint then you can do it by calling request as follow

```
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:<endPoint>
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/user/asset/getAllAssets
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/user/asset/getAllAssets&tag=status:200
```

- You will get COUNT as how many times particular endPoint has been
  called
- You will get COUNT as how many times particular endPoint has been
  called with a particular Status
- To get the average time to execute endPoint you can do
  TOTAL_TIME/COUNT for particular endPoint as well as for the whole
  application

**[More Details are Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987541/metrics-collection-for-spring-boot-rest-apis/56987784#56987784)**

*localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests*

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.21817219999999998
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.1379249
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/{id}.*",
                "/user/asset/getAsset/{assetId}",
                "/user/asset/getAllAssets"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "400",
                "404",
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think i dont need that,because i wont be loggin my internal request which i am doing inside my endpoints.In other words,i dont need the metrics of my Endpoints,i need my metrics/trace related to each request i am doint inside my application.Thanks.

Comment: Hello @AlXx can you please elaborate more with your expected output by adding it in question