# Spring Boot: statistics of APIs using http.server.requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I want to statistics API requests in my Spring Boot 2 application,

> Total number of requests processed
>
> Total number of requests resulted in an OK response
>
> Total number of requests resulted in a 4xx response
>
> Total number of requests resulted in a 5xx response
>
> Average response time of all requests
>
> Max response time of all requests

I want to use Spring Boot Actuator and Micrometer, specifically, *actuator/metrics/http.server.requests*

But I have issues working with tag, Do I need any special configuration for the tag working? 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

Finally, Both http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/test/1 and http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=status:200 work, **by removing the second context path, /travel.**

Comment: You can use **Spring Boot Admin** or can make a request with `localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/endpoint&tag=status:200` See [Metrics Collection for Spring Boot REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987541/metrics-collection-for-spring-boot-rest-apis)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do I need special configuration for the tag working?  {url}/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests works for me.  
But neither {url}/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=status:200 or {url}/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/test/1 work. Just get "This localhost page can’t be found" error.

Comment: Hello @Vicky first make a request at that endpoint which should return 200 OK. Then make request to http.server.requests as it only shows the request which has been made. Or use the spring boot admin. Let me know if you face an issue

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I made a request with 200, but still face the same issue, I edited the question with the screenshots.

Comment: Try for `.../http.server.requests?tag=uri:/test/1`?

Answer (score 2):

While making a request to `/http.server.requests` which *only requires the endpoint of API* to get the metrics for the particular endpoint.

As the application has a context path defined as the i.e `/travel` which is only required for making a request to endpoints.

*Will work fine*

```
http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/test/1
```

*do not work because of the context path in tag=uri*

http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/**travel**/test/1