# How to log request and responses in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, elk

What is the best way log request and responses in spring boot for all applicable http methods (GET, POST, PUT etc) so that at a later point it can be centralized and analyzed using elastic search, log stash and kibana. Appreciate the advises.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot there are many options.  Look into Spring Boot Actuator https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-http or implement a Mapping Filter https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging. I recommend some further research on the topic. If your intention is to obtain metrics Actuator seems the way to go since it's also integrated with metrics and many other features: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will go through these.

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/56987541/10961238